Enable Ceph Dashboard in Microceph
I have a microceph cluster running via snap and would like to enable the ceph dashboard for visibility it disk utilization and other metrics (not for service configuration). There are some instructions on this forum that suggest it's possible, even thought the canonical documentation does not address the dashboard at all. Specifically, the forum provide the following instructions:

microceph.ceph config set mgr mgr/dashboard/ssl false microceph.ceph
mgr module enable dashboard echo -n "p@ssw0rd" >
/var/snap/microceph/current/conf/password.txt microceph.ceph dashboard
ac-user-create -i /etc/ceph/password.txt admin administrator rm
/var/snap/microceph/current/conf/password.txt

The first 2 commands do enable the dashboard and allow it to be accessed over http on port 8080, but there is no way to login.  Since ceph ac-user-create requires a password file and you can't write to the snap directory, as the 3 line of the instructions suggest, there is no way to create a user with a password file.
Is there another way to create a dashboard user or write a password file to a place where the ceph shell can access it? I've tried writing the file (with echo, per step 3 in the instructions) to my user home directory but ac-user-create does not work with -i /home/aossey/password.txt input.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you deploy CEPH using cephadm, you get a password for the dashboard as an output of the bootstrap. In the case of micoceph, the dashboard is disabled by default and there is no dashboard output when you create the cluster.  I'm able to enable the dashboard but I'm unable to find a way to reset/change the admin user password to access the dashboard.  There is no way to login to the dashboard in microceph without knowing or changing the user password.  My question is "how can i find or change the password for the admin user of the dashboard in microceph?" Hope that makes it clear.

The issue is you have mixed the paths /etc/ceph/passwd.txt and /var/snap/microceph/current/conf/password.txt. Change the line
microceph.ceph dashboard ac-user-create -i /etc/ceph/password.txt admin administrator

to
microceph.ceph dashboard ac-user-create -i /var/snap/microceph/current/conf/password.txt admin administrator

